# Android Cordova canvas app lags only for specific device running 2.3.6 Gingerbread when no touch events are being fired

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

My app uses HTML5 canvas and uses Cordova to build an .apk file.

I have tested my app on 5 devices running varying versions of Android OS and of varying hardware capabilities. The only one which lagged was a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, running Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread. I believe it is an OS issue because phones tested with similar/worse hardware do not lag.

When the screen is touched and remains touched, the lag is greatly reduced. I noticed that pixels seem smoothed or anti-aliased when the screen is not touched but more pixelated when the screen is touched, I believe this to be causing the lag. I prefer less pretty with no lag than the opposite. My javascript does not cause this to happen, and so I am stuck on how to resolve it.

---

The following did not solve the problem:

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

and using CSS `image-rendering` settings did not help.

The javascript has touchstart, touchend and touchmove event listeners so I attempted to hack my way by faking the touchmove event even if the user was not touching the screen, although I couldn't get this working and it's not a very elegant solution anyway.

---

I have had this problem for weeks and want my apps to work on all devices.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks, George.